# Is it possible to navigate inside a Redux toolkit action to another screen after an asyncthunk is fullfilled?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

So recently I am working on a react native app. I did wonder how I navigate from a fullfiled action?

I did not find away to be able to do that. What i have so far is this:

1. Dispatch Action
2. Navigate without knowing the result.

How is this achievable.

Some code:
Dispatch in the Submit function:

```
                dispatch(
                    createTopic({
                        title: values.title,
                        subject: values.subject,
                        subsubject: values.subSubject,
                        description: values.description,
                        uid: userUid
                    })
                , [dispatch])




export const createTopic = createAsyncThunk('topic/createTopic',
    async ({title, subject, subsubject, description, uid}) =>{
        try {
            console.log(uid)     
            const response = await firebase.firestore().collection("Users").doc(uid).collection("Topics")
                .doc()
                .set({  
                    title: title,
                    subject: subject,
                    subsubject: subsubject,
                    description: description
                })
                return response
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming since this is `react-native` that you are using `react-navigation`?  It is *possible* to navigate within the Redux action itself using the methods described in the docs page [Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop). But it's probably better to initiate the navigation from the component.

The result of dispatching a thunk action is a `Promise`.  Redux toolkit wraps this Promise so that there are no uncaught errors in your component.  It always resolves to either a success or failure action.  But you can [`unwrap()` the result](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions) to use it with a `try`/`catch`.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const navigation = useNavigation();

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  try {
    // wait for the action to complete successfully
    const response = await dispatch(createTopic(args)).unwrap();
    // then navigate
    navigation.navigate(...);
  } catch (error) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Note: you should not use a `try`/`catch` in your `createAsyncThunk`.  You want errors to be thrown so that they dispatch a `'topic/createTopic/rejected'` action.

Comment: How would the thunk action of this approach look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate from redux action and any were event when you don't have navigation prop, use ref of the navigation container,

eg:

```
export const navigationRef = createRef()

// when adding NavigationContainer add this ref


ie:
<Navigationcontainer ref={navigationRef}>
 {...rest code}
</Navigationcontainer>
```

now you can use that ref to navigate to other screens

eg:

```
navigationRef.current?.navigate('ScreenName', params)
```

use above line the redux action...